# Example of a non quasi coherent sheaf whose global section does not vanish.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Can someone give me an example of a non quasi-coherent sheaf on an affine scheme whose global section doesn't vanish ?

Actually the only examples that I can think of are in a two point affine space consisting of one closed and one generic point.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you want an example that is still a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, or would a sheaf of abelian groups be okay? For the latter, The constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbf{Z}}$ on $X = \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbf{F}_p)$ has global sections $\Gamma(X,\underline{\mathbf{Z}}) = \mathbf{Z}$, but [$\mathbf{Z}$ cannot be an $\mathbf{F}_p$-module](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1277868/116766).

Comment: Thanks! But yes, I wanted an example of $O_X$-module.

Answer (score 3):

I have shown in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1109845/3217) that for the morphism $f:X\to S$ defined by $$f=\coprod_{n\in \mathbb N} \operatorname {Id_{\operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb Z)}}:X=\coprod_{n\in \mathbb N} \operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb Z)\to S=\operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb Z)$$ the direct image sheaf $f_*(\mathcal O_X)$  is a **non** quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_S$-Module.
Since $\Gamma(S,f_*(\mathcal O_X))=\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)=\prod _{n\in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$ is non-zero, the sheaf $f_*(\mathcal O_X)$ is an example of what you require.